# GetBodyCount() always returning 0 in Box2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am using the cocos2d-iphone + Box2d engine, I have a simple call in Box2d to create a body:

```
b2Body *crateBody = world->CreateBody(&crateBodyDef);
```

Then I am printing the newly incremented body count variable through:

```
CCLOG(@"There are %0.0f bodies in the world.", world->GetBodyCount());
```

However, `GetBodyCount()` always returns `0`? I know the body count variable is being incremented, as when I debug and step into `CreateBody(..)` `m_BodyCount` is incrementing, and my inspector returns `1` respectfully.  I do not understand how with `world->GetBodyCount()` simply running a `return m_BodyCount` could this be failing and returning 0?

Hope somebody can help!
Cheers.

I am using SVN rev. r31

Graham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `GetBodyCount()` returning an int? If so, you should use %d in the format string.

Comment: Argh.  Thanks a lot Gerry. That was what's going on.  Didn't notice I was using "f" and representing float. lol. Obj-c is a different beast coming from C#!