# Too Many b2Bodys?

Tags: ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my app after a while, there seems to be a huge issue. There is a build up of b2Bodys from Box2D. I do use some b2Bodys in my app for collision but I would say there is at MOST 10 on the screen at once.

After I debugged the app with Time Profiler in Instruments, I get this as my biggest slowdown:

[image]

So basically it seems that some of my b2Bodys are not getting cleaned up when they should be. **Is there any way to NSLog the amount of b2Bodys in the world so I can check if anything odd is happening?**

Thanks!

Comment: All the information that helped me fix this was from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116497/getbodycount-always-returning-0-in-box2d?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add NSLog statements to the appropriate CreateBody and DestroyBody methods in the b2World class.

Comment: Thanks thats how I ended up debugging it. Turns out I was adding a new b2Body each time my scene was loaded without destroying the old one! :)